# Exception has occurred: ValueError empty range for randrange() (554, 111, -443)

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am having this issue. I am creating a script that will move the mouse to different parts of my monitor and click. Here is the code: `auto.moveTo(random.randint(HP_X[0], HP_X[1]), random.randint(HP_Y[0], HP_Y[1]), 0.5)`
Could someone please help me? Thanks

EDIT - What im trying to do is to click in the top left hand corner and bottom right to make a "box" to click in. `HP_X = [554, 110] HP_Y = [567, 123]`

Auto is `import pyautogui as auto`

Comment: What do `auto`, `HP_X` and `HP_Y` mean? I think you should show a little bit more code. I don't think this is solvable in this state.

Comment: `HP_X[1]` must be greater than `HP_X[0]` otherwise you're going to be trying to draw integers from a range that doesn't make any sense.  We definitely need more information here.  Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `ValueError: empty range for randrange`it means that the range is empty. Probably there isn't any range from **HP_X[0]** to **HP_X[1]**

Comment: I think the `0.5` is the third parameter to `auto.moveTo` rather than part of the calls to get random numbers.

Comment: Oh yes it's true I hadn't seen it :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure arguments to `random.randint()` make sense, i.e., "start" < "stop".  For example, sort them:

```py
auto.moveTo(
    random.randint(*sorted(HP_X[:2])),
    random.randint(*sorted(HP_Y[:2])),
    0.5)
```

You can drop `[:2]` if `HP_{X,Y}` are guaranteed to have only 2 items.